# Lasso on Negative Binomial Regression Model

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

Is there anyway that I can perform LASSO with Negative Binomial Regression on R?
I am performing a negative binomial regression on my dataset because the data are too dispersed to impose poisson regression. Meanwhile, I am also facing some multicollinearity problem. I already tried using `glmnet` with `family = poisson`, but the data is not fitting very well (for both alpha = 0 and alpha = 1).

EDIT: here is variance-covariance table of the negative binomial fit

```
       8.392729e+18  1.239178e+06  -3.624090e+05  1.896258e+17  -3.702521e+17
       1.239178e+06  1.119052e-04   5.201989e-06 -1.877590e+05  -2.558095e+05
      -3.624090e+05  5.201989e-06   5.179343e-06 -8.021543e+04  -1.436381e+05
       1.896258e+17 -1.877590e+05  -8.021543e+04  2.193290e+17   6.413947e+16
      -3.702521e+17 -2.558095e+05  -1.436381e+05  6.413947e+16   2.142183e+17
```

Comment: I think you'll want to take this one to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if this question will even be on-topic on SO; you may want to ask on the [r-help listserv](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-help).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about whether a particular analysis can be run in R.

Comment: it's also going to get hammered on SO because it's just a "how can I?" question, rather than a specific programming question ... Can you give a little more context? I would be tempted to do a quasi-Poisson fit (i.e., fit the model as a Poisson lasso, e.g. with the `glmnet` package, then make a *post hoc* adjustment to the standard errors of the parameters based on the estimated residual deviance ...)

Comment: if there is any extra info that you would like to take a look at, please let me know and I will edit my question

Comment: Have you tried a quasipoisson model then? Based on the very vague description, I think your substantive problem *probably* has to do with a singularity issue. Show us what the `vcov(fit)` gives, `fit` being your glm object.

Comment: There are [lasso methods for collinear predictors](http://www.univie.ac.at/workshop_modelselection/slides/knight/knight_slides.pdf) (and [another one](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2605279/); don't know where/if they've been implemented) ... the `lqa` package looks promising

Answer (score 8):

LASSO and other penalized methods for negative binomial and zero-inflated negative binomial are provided by the [`mpath`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mpath/index.html) package in R, as has been noted on a [more recent Cross Validated page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/162886/28500). One answer on that page, however, indicates some difficulty in using `mpath`. A [recent publication](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bimj.201400143/abstract) illustrates an application of the `mpath` package; a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mpath/vignettes/static_german.pdf) in the R package reproduces the data analysis of that publication.